# How to create multiple value select picker in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipicker

Can we create a picker to select multiple values? What are the other options to select multiple values from the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `UIPickerView` you can't do like this but if we are  using `UITableview` you can do it. [ALPickerview.](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/alpickerview)

Answer (score 3):

Another options to select multiple values from the list is UITableView.
Try the following code and save the selected vales in the array.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
       [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }else{
       [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Check this [link](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2008/10/table-view-multi-row-edit-mode.html), it's fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

well selecting multiple options

I suggest use of the Tableview than pickerview because pickerview sole purpose is to pick any one.

A simple addition of code and an extra array can do the job in the tableview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default UIPickerView with

```
//Objective-C
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView

//Swift
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
```

defining the number of multiple value lines.

[[a link]](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPad_Multiple_Component_UIPickerView_Example_%28Xcode_4%29)

you can see the code from here.